# ArcGIS Pro - Weird boxes when zooming into mosaic raster

Tags: arcgis-pro, mosaic, graphics

I have several large mosaic raster datasets of digital elevation models on my external hard drive. For some datasets I experience weird glitches when zooming in. E.g. At a scale of 1:65000 the raster display is correct but zooming in further produces a strange pattern of rectangles. My first guess was to rebuild pyramids (using cubic instead of nearest neighbor), overviews and statistics but the problem is still present. Other datasets on the hard drive seem to be fine. Here is how it looks like:
[image: GIS Problem]

I just recently started working with ArcGIS again and my colleagues do not have this problem with their version of the dataset.

Version: ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2

Comment: this is not a DEM but hillshade of a DEM so if your original DEM has a big cell size these could be artifact created during hillshade creation

Comment: Yes, in this specific case it is a hillshade. But both pictures are the same dataset at the same spot with two different zoom levels. The underlying data should be the same, if it would be an artifact of hillshade creation I'd expect that it looks the same on all levels. Also if I zoom in further, the pattern changes. More boxes appear instead of just enlarging the old ones. The resolution is 1x1m so we should be able to have enough datapoints also at 1:10000. Maybe, I misunderstand how ArcGIS creates the Map View...

Comment: Just to keep you updated: While playing around in ArcMap I found out that there might be something fundamentally wrong with the mosaic dataset. Apparently, some paths are not correctly set and files are inaccessible. I'll attempt to recreate the dataset from scratch and see if the problem persists.

Comment: After recreating the dataset the problem is now the other way round, so the boxes appear above a certain zoom level >1:45000 but not in the range I am interested in <1:5000. Therefore, my workaround is to turn of the layer visibility for large scales and ignore the problem... Not perfect but still works. If someone has a better solution that would be appreciated.